# Inserting date with format DD-MMM-YYYY into MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I want to insert date into my mysql database either in DD_MM-YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY format.  I tried all options but could not succeed.  Is there any sample program or script for executing the same.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html (literals themselves are always in year-month-day form)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example on how I imported the following table (see: http://www.sqlcourse2.com/items_ordered.html)

```
customerid  order_date   item        quantity  price
10330       30-Jun-1999  Pogo stick  1         28.00
10101       30-Jun-1999  Raft        1         58.00
...
```

into my DB:

```
create table items_ordered (
    customerid int(6),
    order_date date,
    item varchar(30),
    quantity int(6),
    price float(6,2)    
);
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/korulis/Documents/sqltut2 - items_ordered.csv'
IGNORE INTO TABLE items_ordered
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'-- '\r\n'  or '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
(customerid, @var1, item, quantity, price)
SET order_date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%d-%b-%Y');
```

Comment: Check this link for more info on date functions and fromatting:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want to do that.
What you really want is to store the date inside a `DATE` type column with the default format `YYYY-MM-DD` and leave your application to format the date as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The **DATETIME** type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in '`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`' format.

The **TIMESTAMP** data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '2001-01-01 00:00:01

The **DATE** type is used for  DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format

[SEE HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

To insert the date, use [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to extract the components of the date and [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to build a date from the components in the format required by MySQL.

When reading the date, use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to transform the date back into the original format.